# vulkan-1.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format in GCC

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, vulkan

The errors:

> C:\VulkanSDK\1.0.17.0\Bin/vulkan-1.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

or

> C:\VulkanSDK\1.0.17.0\Bin32/vulkan-1.lib: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

I using Eclipse Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

Compilers:

Cygwin 2.5.2(0.297/5/3)

MinGW-w64 gcc (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0

flags: -m64 or -m32

Can someone point me what I am doing wrong, or send me a example workspace with correct setup?

It is my first cross-platform project, so I probably doing something wrong.

I chose Eclipse from simple reason, it is almost same on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Why do you use old SDK?

Comment: By any chance, don't you have the 32-bit and 64-bit versions swapped while linking?

Comment: Yes I swap "bin" and "bin32" whenever I swap "-m64" and "-m32"

Comment: Are you building the vulcan library?  Are you building it with debug symbols?

Comment: No I not building it, I just want to add it to my (first) cross-platform project, that why I chose to use eclipse and gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Update your SDK (latest ATMOW is 17)

2) That `vulkan-1.lib` in `$VULKAN_SDK/Bin` is **MSVC++** library and there's no guarantee, it will work in **gcc** (doesn't for me - Cygwin is supposed to have some support, but it simply doesn't work for me).

Try to link directly to the `vulkan-1.dll` (  that is supply `-L$WINDIR/System32` (x64 on x64 os) or `-L$WINDIR/SysWOW64` (32 on 64) instead of the SDK paths  ).

Otherwise you will need to build The Loader from source, which will be pain for Cygwin/MinGW (don't think there is official support yet). Or, you know, abandon Eclipse and join us on the dark side.

Comment: I update to version 17 and try Cygwin 2.5.2 and MinGW-w64 gcc 6.1.0. Both 32 and 64 bit from both paths ${VULKAN_SDK}, and ${windir}, none of 8 valid combinations work.

Comment: I will need to compile app for Windows and Linux, I really want that much, when want one IDE for two systems? I do not mentioned this in the question, because I did not think it mater for answer, but you think is better to have Visual studio on Windows and something else on Linux?

Comment: If you can, try Cygwins gcc (not MinGWs nor Cygwin/MinGW). And make sure it links to the (proper) vulkan-1.dll (i.e. to System32 for x64 binary). That combination worked for me anyway...

Comment: Yeah, using MS VS on Windows may be better because all developer users of your project will have the environment they are used to on their OS. People usually use Cmake for the transformation to whatever they want. Alternatively you can try just to use the MSVC++ commandline linker, but that would probably break your IDE debugging capability.

Comment: Yeah f**k Eclipse I'm joining the dark side even if it will cost me precious gigabytes. I have been wrestling with this stupid convoluted garbage for too long and I'm D.O.N.E.